# VS Code open terminal Bash (MSYS2) in current path in Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

I changed the terminal shell profile from MYSYS to MSYS2 to be the default and it stopped to open the terminal in the project directory.
Here is my settings of the new profile which is using MYSYS2:

```
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
  "[go]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.organizeImports": false
    },
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "golang.go"
  },
  "go.formatTool": "gofmt",
  "typescript.tsserver.watchOptions": {},
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[gotmpl]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "golang.go"
  },
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {
    "127.0.0.1": "linux",
    "sdk-shared-dev.q2devstack.com": "linux"
  },
  "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
  "launch": {
    "configurations": []
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "bash (MSYS2)",
  "redhat.telemetry.enabled": true,
  "[xml]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "redhat.vscode-xml"
  },
  "vscode-spring-boot.rewrite.reconcile-prompt": false,
  "lldb.dbgconfig": {
  
  },
  "terminal.integrated.scrollback": 10000,
  "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
  "debug.onTaskErrors": "abort",
  "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
  "[python]": {
    "editor.formatOnType": true
  },
  "[cpp]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-vscode.cpptools"
  },
  "files.associations": {
    "*.html": "html"
  },
  "glsllint.glslifyOptions": {

  },
  "rust-analyzer.inlayHints.typeHints.enable": false,
  "editor.inlayHints.enabled": "offUnlessPressed",
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": {
      "source": "PowerShell",
      "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    },
    "Command Prompt": {
      "path": [
        "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
        "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
      ],
      "args": [],
      "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    },
    "Git Bash": {
      "source": "Git Bash"
    },
    "bash (MSYS2)": {
      "path": "C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe",
      "args": [
        "--login",
        "-i"
      ]
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "",
  "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    
  },
  "go.toolsManagement.autoUpdate": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    
  }
}
```

How can I make it to open in the project root?

### Update

I did try to add `"terminal.integrated.cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"` but after restart it didn't work.

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": {
      "source": "PowerShell",
      "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    },
    "Command Prompt": {
      "path": [
        "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
        "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
      ],
      "args": [],
      "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    },
    "Git Bash": {
      "source": "Git Bash"
    },
    "bash (MSYS2)": {
      "path": "C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe",
      "args": [
        "--login",
        "-i"
      ]
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "",
  "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    
  },
  "go.toolsManagement.autoUpdate": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    
  },
  "terminal.integrated.cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `terminal.integrated.cwd` property at a top level object of your settings file like that:

```
"terminal.integrated.cwd": ${workspaceFolder}
```

Also that path might be relative, for example:
`${workspaceFolder}/your_nested_folder`,

Please note, that VS Code restarting might be required.

Comment: see my updated in the main post , in short didnt work